# Can hadoop slaves exist on different install directory?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I have a 3 node `hadoop` cluster with one namenode and two datanodes.
The namenode resides in : `/opt/hadoop/` directory and datanodes reside in `/mnt/hadoop/` directory.

In `.bashrc` of namenode is :

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::")
export HADOOP_INSTALL=/opt/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
```

and datanodes is :

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::")
export HADOOP_INSTALL=/mnt/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
```

However,when I start the cluster from namenode , I get from the **datanodes** saying 
`/opt/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: No such file or directory` .

It seems to me that slaves are referring `/opt/hadoop/` instead of `/mnt/hadoop`. Why is this ?
Should the slaves reside in the same path as namenodes ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use start-dfs.sh (start-all.sh is depricated now which internally invokes start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh utilities for starting HDFS and YARN services respectively) utility for starting all HDFS services(namenode and datanodes), then you got to maintain the directory structure (keeping hadoop artifacts and configuration files) in all nodes.

If you are not maintaining in the same directory structure, you have to execute the following command in all slave nodes for starting datanodes.

```
$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh start datanode
```

For starting yarn slave services you have to use the following command in all slave nodes.

```
$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh start nodemanager
```